# Reboot and select proper boot device problem after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

Hi I have a toshiba satellite laptop.
I recently decided to replace my os which used to be 
Windows 10 with ubuntu, and used a USB key to store the 
Linux installation, plugged it in, successfully installed 
Ubuntu and erased windows(as it says). After the installation
A message popped up telling my restart the computer in order to 
Start using the new os. After doing so I get his blank screen 
With the message:

`Reboot and select proper boot device`
Or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key
Can't access anything now, btw I did enter to BIOS and set everything back
On default after the installation of the Linux and it still doesn't work
Can anybody tell me what can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the same problem as mine, go to BIOS and go to security. 
 Navigate to `Select Trusted file for booting`. 
 `HDD0`(If you have one harddrive)
`ubuntu`(I don't remember the exact order, but look for these files)
`EFI`(I'm positive that it is EFI>>>Shimx)
`Shimx`(I don't know what it is called but it looks like Shimx or Shimax something like that)
 Press enter 
Call it ubuntu enter enter again
F10
 This should help!

Comment: Once I go to security I don't have the select trusted file for booting option, the options are BIOS pass HDD pass and secure bot off/on , I've searched thru the whole bios system couldn't find it

Comment: Set bios password, nd it should let you. I had the exact same problem with my acer aspire e15!

Comment: If my answer helps, press the checkmark please!

Answer (score 0):

This blog helped. I had same issue while installing Ubuntu Server 18.xx. 
Thanks for the post, much appreciated

steps taken:

1. In BIOS security , set password for user
2. Go to boot tab and enable all ( few are disabled, e.g.: UEFI boot,Boot USB devices first).

Comment: I guess the blog you are talking about is the previous answer.  In such cases, it is better to upvote the answer (which as a new user you cannot do until you have at least 15 reputation).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reinstall Ubuntu, and this time, check the box reading:

> Allow updates after/while installing...

While installing Ubuntu. This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I don't see how this could solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue I installed Ubuntu 3 times when I was scrolling through this someone said to go into bios and when I went to bios **in the boot option there was a drive called Ubuntu which was not selected so I just selected that and booted from it and everything worked**